# AssemblyFileVersion is null, but it should equal AssemblyVersion

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

I have a .Net4.6 C# Windows Forms project in Visual Studio 2015.

My AssemblyInfo.cs versioning is as follows:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("")]
```

When I build my application, I get the following values:

```
AssemblyVersion: 1.0.5751.22274
AssemblyFileVersion:
```

In all of my other projects, I get the following values:

```
AssemblyVersion: 1.0.5751.22274
AssemblyFileVersion: 1.0.5751.22274
```

Is there a reason why one project would not set the `AssemblyFileVersion`, and another would?

**Update:**
It works if I comment out the `AssemblyFileVersion` line as follows:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
//[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("")]
```

My other projects (.net4.6 WinForms VS2015) do not require me to comment out this line. What is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not `null`, it's an empty string. You could just remove the attribute altogether; perhaps you specified `[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion()]` in the other assemblies?

I'd favor omitting the attribute over specifying it with an empty value.

Comment: I'm still not sure of the actual difference, but since commenting out fixes the issue for all projects, that is an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0")]
```

Or not set the tag AssemblyVersion at all.

```
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("")]
```